# Use tf.image.ssim_multiscale for a batch of images in sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I am trying to use SSIM as loss value for my Keras Sequential model. The output value is a set of 6 images - (6, 32, 28, 3). I want to implement a custom loss function for the model.fit() function but cannot understand how to implement this. I am attaching what I have tried before-

```
def ssim_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1-tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim_multiscale(y_true, y_pred, 2.0))
```

```
def ssim_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  loss = 0
  for i in range(6):
    loss += tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim_multiscale(y_true[i], y_pred[i], 2.0))
  return loss
```

y_true shape is same as y_pred which I have checked. These both solutions do not work. I do not know how to access each element of y_pred. My input shape is  - (6, 192, 56, 3). Please help. TIA

Comment: Anyone with any type of contribution please comment. I am doing a project and stuck at this phase for a day now.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33840#issuecomment-633715778) reference may help you?